# Split access.log file by dates using command line tools

Tags: bash, text, logfiles

I have a Apache access.log file, which is around 35GB in size. Grepping through it is not an option any more, without waiting a great deal.

I wanted to split it in many small files, by using date as splitting criteria.

Date is in format `[15/Oct/2011:12:02:02 +0000]`. Any idea how could I do it using only bash scripting, standard text manipulation programs (grep, awk, sed, and likes), piping and redirection?

Input file name is `access.log`. I'd like output files to have format such as `access.apache.15_Oct_2011.log` (that would do the trick, although not nice when sorting.)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One way using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    split("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec ", months, " ")
    for (a = 1; a <= 12; a++)
        m[months[a]] = sprintf("%02d", a)
}
{
    split($4,array,"[:/]")
    year = array[3]
    month = m[array[2]]

    print > FILENAME"-"year"_"month".txt"
}' incendiary.ws-2009
```

This will output files like:

```
incendiary.ws-2010-2010_04.txt
incendiary.ws-2010-2010_05.txt
incendiary.ws-2010-2010_06.txt
incendiary.ws-2010-2010_07.txt
```

Against a 150 MB log file, the answer by chepner took 70 seconds on an 3.4 GHz 8 Core Xeon E31270, while this method took 5 seconds.

Original inspiration: "[How to split existing apache logfile by month?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11714105/430062)"

Comment: You are right, Sir. I've just tested perl solution as well, and awk solution was faster by 3x. I suspect it has to do with the fact that awk example doesn't use regular expressions but simple string splitting, which might be more efficient. Marking as an Accepted answer.

Comment: Oh, and I'm definitely using this on production against 20 GB files with no problems now.  Takes about 2 GB/minute on my system.

Comment: Similar performances here as well: ~1 minute / ~2.5gb. Thanks!

Comment: The only thing is, I need date extracted as well - my daily log sizes are well over 400MB these days.. Could you modify the script to include dates as well?

Comment: Shouldn't 'split($4,array,"[:/]");' instruction should come before 'year = array[3]'

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith Your output file name are wrong because you encoded the `month` variable with two digits `sprintf("%02d", a)`. Can you please fix your output file names so as to avoid confusion ?

Answer (score 10):

Pure bash, making one pass through the access log:

```
while read; do
    [[ $REPLY =~ \[(..)/(...)/(....): ]]

    d=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    m=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    y=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}

    #printf -v fname "access.apache.%s_%s_%s.log" ${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1:3}
    printf -v fname "access.apache.%s_%s_%s.log" $y $m $d

    echo "$REPLY" >> $fname
done < access.log
```

Comment: The method in my answer is dramatically faster: Against a 150 MB log file, this answer took **70 seconds** on an 3.4 GHz 8 Core Xeon E31270, while the method in mine took **5 seconds**.

Comment: However, this answer creates logs files on a day basis not on a monthly basis. This does less, no wonder it is faster.

Comment: @i.am.michiel The reason this is slower is that iterating through the input is much faster in `awk` than in `bash`; the number of output files is not really relevant.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an `awk` version that outputs lexically sortable log files.

Some efficiency enhancements: all done in one pass, only generate `fname` when it is not the same as before, close `fname` when switching to a new file (otherwise you might run out of file descriptors).

```
awk -F"[]/:[]" '
BEGIN {
  m2n["Jan"] =  1;  m2n["Feb"] =  2; m2n["Mar"] =  3; m2n["Apr"] =  4;
  m2n["May"] =  5;  m2n["Jun"] =  6; m2n["Jul"] =  7; m2n["Aug"] =  8;
  m2n["Sep"] =  9;  m2n["Oct"] = 10; m2n["Nov"] = 11; m2n["Dec"] = 12;
}
{
  if($4 != pyear || $3 != pmonth || $2 != pday) {
    pyear  = $4
    pmonth = $3
    pday   = $2

    if(fname != "")
      close(fname)

    fname  = sprintf("access_%04d_%02d_%02d.log", $4, m2n[$3], $2)
  }
  print > fname
}' access-log
```

Answer (score 4):

Perl came to the rescue:

```
cat access.log | perl -n -e'm@\[(\d{1,2})/(\w{3})/(\d{4}):@; open(LOG, ">>access.apache.$3_$2_$1.log"); print LOG $_;'
```

Well, it's not exactly "standard" manipulation program, but it's made for text manipulation nevertheless.

I've also changed order of arguments in file name, so that files are named like access.apache.yyyy_mon_dd.log for easier sorting.

Answer (score 4):

I combined Theodore's and Thor's solutions to use Thor's efficiency improvement and daily files, but retain the original support for IPv6 addresses in combined format file.

```
awk '
BEGIN {
  m2n["Jan"] =  1;  m2n["Feb"] =  2; m2n["Mar"] =  3; m2n["Apr"] =  4;
  m2n["May"] =  5;  m2n["Jun"] =  6; m2n["Jul"] =  7; m2n["Aug"] =  8;
  m2n["Sep"] =  9;  m2n["Oct"] = 10; m2n["Nov"] = 11; m2n["Dec"] = 12;
}
{
  split($4, a, "[]/:[]")
  if(a[4] != pyear || a[3] != pmonth || a[2] != pday) {
    pyear  = a[4]
    pmonth = a[3]
    pday   = a[2]

    if(fname != "")
      close(fname)

    fname  = sprintf("access_%04d-%02d-%02d.log", a[4], m2n[a[3]], a[2])
  }
  print >> fname
}'
```

Comment: This is really impressive! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Kind of ugly, that's bash for you:

```
    for year in 2010 2011 2012; do
       for month in jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec; do
           for day in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ... 31 ; do
               cat access.log | grep -i $day/$month/$year > $day-$month-$year.log
            done
        done
     done
```

Comment: very clever, thanks ;) this would work great for small file (filesize less than amount of ram), as it loops through entire file about 1,116 times :)

Comment: very true, its not an efficient script. it would be good for occasional use. Thanks!

Comment: it would be faster to unroll the outer loop and process the file in two passes - on the first pass split the file into entries by year. The second pass would then process each year file and split the entries by date. It may even be faster to unroll the second loop and process the file in three passes.

Comment: grepping for the date will accidentally delete stacktraces etc, i.e. any lines that don't contain a date will be deleted.  Usually it is these lines that are the most interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I made a slight improvement to Theodore's answer so I could see progress when processing a **very** large log file.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    split("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec ", months, " ")
    for (a = 1; a <= 12; a++)
        m[months[a]] = a
}
{
    split($4, array, "[:/]")
    year = array[3]
    month = sprintf("%02d", m[array[2]])

    current = year "-" month
    if (last != current)
        print current
    last = current

    print >> FILENAME "-" year "-" month ".txt"
}
```

Also I found that I needed to use `gawk` (`brew install gawk` if you don't have it) for this to work on Mac OS X.