# Shell Scripting (Extracting the logs for last 24 hours)

Tags: shell

I have a huge logfile1 (Linux) with below date format & I want to extract the past 24 hrs of data & write into different file with a shell script. Please help me to achieve the task?

```
----------
03/03/2016 05:40:42 AM QWTRAB1 AMQ7315: Failed to put message to accounting queue. Reason(2053
----------
03/03/2016 05:40:42 AM QWTRAB1 AMQ7315: Failed to put message to accounting queue. Reason(2053
----------
03/03/2016 05:40:46 AM QWTRAB1 AMQ7315: Failed to put message to accounting queue. Reason(2053
----------
03/03/2016 05:40:46 AM QWTRAB1 AMQ7315: Failed to put message to accounting queue. Reason(2053
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something similar to [Split access.log file by dates using command line tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687054/split-access-log-file-by-dates-using-command-line-tools):

`split.awk`:

```
{
    split($1,array,"[:/]");
    year = array[3]
    month = array[2]
    day = array[1]

    print > FILENAME"-"year"_"month"_"day".txt"
}
```

command:

```
awk -f split.awk your_log_file.log
```

Comment: ./test.sh
+ awk $'BEGIN {\n    split("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec ", months, " ")\n    for (a = 1; a <= 12; a++)\n        m[months[a]] = a\n}\n{\n    split($4,array,"[:/]");\n    year = array[3]\n    month = sprintf("%02d", m[array[2]])\n\n    print > /apphome/mqm/logs/NewFile"-"year"_"month".txt"\n}' /apphome/mqm/logs/MQLOGS.OUT.0303160800.txt
awk: cmd. line:10: (FILENAME=/apphome/mqm/logs/MQLOGS.OUT.0303160800.txt FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted

Comment: @Krishna, i've updated my answer. If you really have '------' lines in your log file you would have to filter them out first...

Answer (score 0):

Try `awk` command providing the date range

```
awk '$0 >= "03/03/2016 05:40" && $0 <= "03/02/2016 05:40"'
```

UPDATE:

```
#!/bin/bash
position=0
length=10
PREVDATE=`date -d "-1 days" +"%d-%m-%Y"`
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        LOGDATE=${line:position:length}
        if [ "$PREVDATE" = "$LOGDATE" ]; then
                echo $line >> $PREVDATE.log
        fi;     
done < "$1"
```

If you want to get the log for previous day. You can run this script in crontab everyday once. Save the given script in a file called logparser.sh. Provide the main log file as argument. You can find the parsed data in new log file name with previous date.

try `$./logparser.sh logfilename.log`

Comment: I want to do this on daily basis with a cron job

Comment: @Krishna I have updated the answer. You can run this script as crontab !!

Comment: Looks like it's not giving the output in write format

Comment: + IFS='
+ LOGDATE=03/07/2016
+ [ 06-03-2016 '= 03/07/2016 ]
+ read -r line
+ IFS='
+ LOGDATE=03/07/2016
+ [ 06-03-2016 '= 03/07/2016 ]
+ read -r line
+ IFS='
+ LOGDATE=03/07/2016
+ [ 06-03-2016 '= 03/07/2016 ]
+ read -r line
+ IFS='
+ [[ -n ' ]]

Comment: Looks like it's not giving the output in right format , when I try to execute the logpraser.sh with the logfilename.log as a argument

Comment: @Krishna if you run everyday. It will parse the yesterday's log data into file. You can modify the DATE part as per you requirement. !! I did it like that bcoz if you run it once a day it will parse ur all the log of yesterday's date.